# I need to retrieve facebook user language with php

Tags: facebook

I'm building a very simple facebook app in which I would like to retrieve the facebook user language.
Since now, I retrieve the browser language to give the right language for the user but I think that retrieving the facebook user language is better and more precise.
Is there someone who can help a beginner?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [user node](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user) field `locale`.

Comment: Thank's for your help, i'm looking after the facebook doc hopping to find the way, is there a difference if i use framework like codeigniter and angular js? it' not my code  but I have to do with and the goal is to internationalize it.

Comment: You should use what framework works for you. It's just the matter of taste.